# Validate positive number with Bean Validation

Tags: java, validation, javabeans

I am trying to validate numeric values that should be greater than zero with custom Bean Validation, but the problem is to validate any numeric value: Integer, Float, Double.... with a single custom validator like the following:

@PositiveNumber
Integer int;

@PositiveNumber
Double double;

is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem using the following solution.

```
public class PositiveNumberValidator implements ConstraintValidator<PositiveNumber, Object> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(PositiveNumber constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object number, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (number instanceof Integer) {
            Integer num = (Integer) number;
            return (num > 0);

        } else if (number instanceof Double) {
            Double num = (Double) number;
            return (num > 0d);

        } else if (number instanceof Long) {
            Long num = (Long) number;
            return (num > 0L);

        } else if (number instanceof Float) {
         Float num = (Float) number;
            return (num > 0F);

        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is PositiveNumber class.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly mean with your prerequisite for "custom Bean Validation", but a standard way to do this is to use `javax.validation.constraints.Min` like this

```
@Min(value = 0)
```

Comment: According to https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/bean-validation002.html @Min works on integer values.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for natural numbers,I think you can use the **regex** pattern to get the desired output , something like that

> `@Pattern(regexp = "[\\s]*[0-9]*[1-9]+",message="msg")`